# Spring cloud stream binder kafka doesn't run on Netty

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-webflux

I would like to build a streaming engine using Kafka Steams and Spring Webflux on top of Netty to provide continues state changes over the HTTP. What I've noticed if I have

```
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka')
```

dependency in my gradle file spring boot app starts with embedded Tomcat instead of Netty.

If I remove

```
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka')
```

than it starts with Netty.

Is this some kind of a design decision not to provide reactive capabilities with `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` or am I doing something wrong? Full gradle config looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M4'
        springKafkaVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'
        kafkaStreamsVersion = '1.0.0'
        confluentVersion = '4.0.0'
        avroVersion = '1.8.2'
        avroPluginVersion = '0.12.0'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
        classpath "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin:gradle-avro-plugin:$avroPluginVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro"

group = 'eu.lkokhreidze'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/" }
}

ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.M3'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka')
    compile("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:$springKafkaVersion")

    compile("org.apache.avro:avro:$avroVersion")
    compile("org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:$kafkaStreamsVersion")
    compile("io.confluent:kafka-streams-avro-serde:$confluentVersion")

    compileOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:$springCloudVersion"
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn(generateAvroJava)
compileTestJava.dependsOn(generateTestAvroJava)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not intentional. The 2.0 version of the binder is still under development; spring-cloud-stream's actuator endpoints might not have been migrated yet.

BTW, I see you are using boot M4 - the current 2.0 milestone is M7.

I don't know if that will solve your issue; you may be able to exclude the mvc jars, but I don't know if the actuators will work, or if you can disable stream's actuator, so YMMV.

You should be able to use spring-kafka directly, though.

Comment: I tried with M7 as well, same issue. But thanks for clarification, it makes sense. I will try to find out what I can do with it.

Comment: I opened [issue #1163](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1163).